# What's the difference between 'dotnet-sdk-2.1.401-osx-x64.pkg' and 'dotnet-sdk-2.1.401-osx-gs-x64.pkg'?

Tags: .net, .net-core

Trying to install the .NET 2.1 Core on my Mac, but I'm a little confused as there's two seemingly-identical files from Microsoft:

- dotnet-sdk-2.1.401-osx-x64.pkg
- dotnet-sdk-2.1.401-osx-gs-x64.pkg *(Note the 'gs')*

They both seem to refer to the same versions, both install the .NET Core SDK, the .NET Core Runtime and the ASP.NET Core runtime, and they both produce this seemingly-identical screen at the end:

[image]

So what's the difference?

Comment: You can also find when they introduced this, and the "nj" build. Anyway, don't waste your time on such as nobody should use them, https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/releases.json

Comment: Just somebody having his brain turned off on Monday morning: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/961

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same. There's no difference between the `-gs` and non`-gs` variants:

> They're the same. We needed an easy way to track downloads from either the 'getting started' pages versus downloads that came from other places. Copy and rename to the rescue :-)

[source](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/961)

Comment: At first I was going to comment on whomever implemented that as clearly being a newbie on designing it to track it that way, but if I take off my 'purist programmer' hat for a second, it actually *is* a simple way to track that kind of info.  You could easily grep the server logs of what was served up and I don't remember/recall if the referrer info is in there.  It's actually simple enough that I'd forgive them for it.  And +1 for pointing out I could've just used the checksum feature.  Didn't even think of that, but now it's in my arsenal.